# Getting "Error: Safe Proxy contract is not deployed in the current network" after calling safeFactory.deploySafe()

Tags: metamask, gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I was able to deploy a safe proxy contract on the Rinkeby testnet using [this](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/build/sdks/core-sdk#2.-deploy-a-new-safe) but I am facing an issue. After calling `safeFactory.deploySafe()`, it gives an error `Error: Safe Proxy contract is not deployed in the current network`. I think it is because the transaction is not confirmed yet and it just throws an error. Now, as I am using Metamask, so Metamask gives the notification about the transaction success and I am able to see the address of my deployed safe proxy contract on the Rinkeby Etherscan. I wanted to understand, is it normal to get this error and then manually get the deployed safe proxy contract address from the Etherscan or not? My use case is whenever a user creates a safe then I should be able to store their deployed safe proxy contract address on my backend automatically and not manually by asking the user to go and check Etherscan and then save it on the backend via some frontend UI.
I am using [Safe Core SDK](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/build/sdks/core-sdk) v1.1.1 and [web3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3) v1.6.1 for creating the ethAdapter.

Comment: Hmm I would assume this happens because the node that is used with the sdk is not yet aware of the deployed contract. I would say this should be handled by the sdk, so probably worth opening an issue for this.

Comment: Thanks, @Richard. I will open an issue for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed by the gnosis team. https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/issues/128